# printing exception not working pandas read csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, exception

This code below will read a csv file into pandas, but when I am testing it out on different file types (.xls, .txt) my exception isnt working. Im just getting a

`print(df.head())
NameError: name 'df' is not defined`

I also was thinking that if two .csv files were placed into the same directory where my script.py file is located that it would throw an exception but it doesnt.

Would anyone have a tip on how to make my exception work if a filename that is not CSV and also if more than one CSV file was in the directory? Thanks

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import time

import os



try:
        for filename in os.listdir('.'):
            if filename.endswith('.csv'):
                if os.path.isfile(filename):
                    df = pd.read_csv(
                        filename,index_col='Date', parse_dates=True)




except Exception as e:
        print(
                'There was an error processing this file.'
                )


print(df.head())
```

Comment: Your error is occurring after your exception catch block. Read up on scoping inside loops for why df isn't defined

Comment: your `df` is defined inside `try`. your last `print()` is out of scope.